# How do I display children for every parent in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I create a query that display every parent with its children rather than to display all parents first then children. For example, right now, the mySQL table shows all COMPUTERS and then DRIVES. I want it to display for every computer, display the drives associated with that computer. I.E.:

```
 COMPUTER   DRIVE        PID         ID 
 dell                    1 
 apple                   2
 apple                   3
 hp                      4
 hp                      5
            WD300FV                  1
            WD440GB                  1
            WD55                     2
            WD44X                    2...
```

I want it displayed like this where every computer is shown a list of its drives:

```
 COMPUTER   DRIVE        PID     
 dell                    1 
            WD300FV      1
            WD440GB      1
 apple                   2
            WD55         2
            WD44X        2
 apple                   3.....
```

Where computer has a parent ID and drive has an ID.

When I do this query `SELECT * FROM table` it doesn't create rows as I would like it to be displayed. I want every row that shows a computer to display a list of drives below the computer row.

Comment: What's the query you are using like and what is the structure for the tables involved?

Comment: its a self join table so its the same structure

Comment: No it's a very bad representation of a 2 level hierarchy. A self join table would use a primary key referenced by a foreign key. However adjacency lists are more commonly used with MySQL since it doesn't support recursive queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would question your table structure.  I would think computers and drives should be in two separate but related tables, since they are two different things, potentially with their own properties.

computer table:

```
computer_id |  manufacturer
---------------------------
1           |  dell
2           |  apple
3           |  hp
```

computer_id would be auto-incrementing primary key

drive table:

```
drive_id   |  computer_id  |  name
-----------------------------------
1          |  1            | WD300FV
2          |  1            | WD440GB
3          |  2            | WD55
4          |  2            | WD44X
5          |  3            | XYZ
```

drive_id would be auto-incrementing primary key

computer_id would have index (and possibly foreign key constraint if you are using InnoDB and wanted to enforce a relationship to computer table)

Then you would query like this:

```
SELECT c.computer_id, c.manufacturer, d.drive_id, d.name
FROM computer AS c
INNER JOIN drive AS d ON c.computer_id = d.computer_id
ORDER BY c.computer_id ASC, d.drive_id ASC
```

If, for whatever reason, you didn't want to go with a normalized structure like I have proposed and instead use a de-normalized structure like similar to what you already have, you should at least consider doing your de-normalization in a more sane way. There is no need for your `pid` logic at all if you just structured your table like this:

```
computer  |  drive
------------------
dell      | WD300FV
dell      | WD4440GB
apple     | WD55
apple     | WD44X
hp        | XYZ
```

You are just adding a level of complexity that doesn't need to be there.  You could easily sort your result by "computer":

```
SELECT computer, drive FROM table
ORDER BY computer ASC, drive ASC
```

With no schema changes at all you could query like this:

```
SELECT computer, drive, CASE WHEN pid = '' THEN id ELSE pid END as `sort_id`
FROM table
ORDER BY `sort_id` ASC, drive ASC
```

Comment: I know the structure is NOT normalized but that's what the previous guy did. :/

Comment: @netrox Does that make it right or impossible to change?  It seems you have a pretty simple table to where refactoring would be extremely easy.

Comment: I agree..  but that table has been used so many times and two separate apps rely on that table. Can't change it. Yes, it's poorly designed but stuck with that. I even created a database that's normalized (disks and systems) but it always have to go back to that table formatted that way.

Comment: OK.  Why do you need a self-join to order by pid?  Why not just `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY pid ASC, drive ASC`?  You rows with empty strings for `drive` would sort first within the `pid` grouping, placing the `computer` listings first within the `pid` grouping.

Comment: I left one important column...   drives have the ID of their computers. (where pid is system and id is drives)

Comment: Ah... now I see why you were trying a self-join.  This probably isn't necessary though. See my updated answer. I am assuming that those empty values for pid are empty strings. If they are actually nulls, you could do `COALESCE(pid, id) AS sort_id`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rows in the order that you need, you could use this:

```
select
  computer,
  drive,
  coalesce(pid, id)
from
  your_table
order by
  coalesce(pid, id), computer is null, drive is not null
```

this will order rows by `pid` or (if `pid` is null) by `id`, and put rows where computer is not null at the top (since `computer is null` is evaluated as 0 when it's false, and 1 when it's true), and then rows with drive null at the top.

(of course, if computer and drive can't be null at the same time, you could just order by just `computer is null`)

You might also consider this order by clause:

```
order by coalesce(pid, id), computer is null, computer, drive is not null, drive
```

Comment: just added a column name... that query doesn't list correctly. I think I left one important column out that affects the query.

Comment: @netrox i added `coalesce` function, to return `pid` if not null, `id` otherwise. Notice that my query will work if your columns with blank values have null values, it they are empty strings instead, you have to modify the query.